# How can I insert a file in SQL Server using ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I'm developing an ASP.NET app (C#) that connect to SQL Server 2008 using ADO.NET entity framework.

The user of this app can select an image from his local hard drive to insert in SQL Server. How can I do this?

I know how to store the image into SQL Server but I don't know how to upload the image to the server (using FileUpload server control?).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing uploaded file to SQL server you can look at this answer of mine :

[How do you store a picture in an image column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744589/how-do-you-store-a-picture-in-an-image-column/744603#744603)

In this example, **uploadInput** is a file input control, you can use it as FileUpload control in ASP.NET.

For using File upload Control in ASP.NET [here is a good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Well, to upload to the web-server you just need an `<input type="file" .../>`. At ASP.NET, this should be available in the [`Request.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) collection.

In SQL Server, you'll want a `varbinary(max)` (or `image` in older versions).

The big question before pushing them into SQL Server is: how big are they? If they aren't massive, you can just treat them as a `byte[]`; just buffer from the [`InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) and send. Here's a fairly generic way of buffering a `Stream` to a single `byte[]`:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
```

For massive files (which perhaps don't belong in the db unless you are using the SQL 2008 filestream extensions), you'll want to chunk it. [Here's an old reply](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/6c9e5e75ae39826b#998c53ff8afb02eb) I used for chunking (before SQL 2005) - but it shows the overall idea.

Comment: Hi Marc, i use the 'image' type in SQL05 for my application but i didn't know that it wasn't the preferred type. Why is 'varbinary(max)' more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a varbinary(MAX) column: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Search on Google yielded this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=398883&seqNum=2

Note that in his example, he is using the Image data type in SQL Server 2005.  That type is being phased out in favor of varbinary.  You would have to change that code to fit your specific schema needs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the entity framework, but this is how you [do this in vanilla ado.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309158)