# TGraphicField equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, delphi, freepascal

I'm just looking for an equivalent or a method in c#

I have this class defined in delphi

`TGraphicField`

I wonder if there's something I could use in c# who would do the same or I have to create my own class.

Comment: For people who know C# but not Delphi, it might help if you [edit] your question and explain what it is you're trying to do and what database you're using. Most people using C# are not necessarily familiar with what a `TGraphicField` is, and it's hard to suggest a replacement for it if you don't.

Comment: I don't know delphi and I'm at a absic level of c#, ultimatly I don't know what a `TGraphicField` do even after readed freepascal website so I came here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `TGraphicField` is to store images within a database.

There isn't a single way to handle this in C#.  Basically, in C#, you'd just use a BLOB column in the database, and [serialize to and from an image yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548401/how-to-save-image-in-database-using-c-sharp).  This is most commonly handled via the [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) class, which provides routines for treating a `byte[]` as a `Stream`, as well as saving into the `MemoryStream` then using [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to convert back into a `byte[]`.

Comment: Doesn't Delphi TGraphicField have some small header (X,Y, type) ?