# Add image in Edit Top 200 Rows - SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, database, image, sql-server-2012

I have never used images in a table before and I am trying to make some test cases of data, but I cannot figure out how to insert an image in the table. Right now I am trying a full path url to an image, but it just throws an error.

[image]

I made the datatype as "image" as well.

Thanks!

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s ah I see! Well in this case, can I still the Edit Top 200 Rows to add images(varbinary now), or do I need to do it through a query? I still get an error when using varbinary. thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can *edit* binary data columns in the Mgmt Studio ...

Comment: @marc_s is right, you can't edit it in SSMS... Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548401/how-to-save-image-in-database-using-c-sharp

Comment: Boo. :/ I decided to go along with adding the images to my MVC project and internally just linking them with `img src`, is that "okay" to do?