# How to convert an image to bytes to save it in a database and retrieve from database?

Tags: c#, image, byte

I am trying to convert an image to bytes to save it in a database and retrieve from database.

How can I do that?

Comment: The question was already answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548401/how-to-save-image-in-database-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx), save the image to it, and use the [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the bytes:

This code assumes you have an `Image` named `image`:

```
byte[] bytes;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```