# saving image in sql data base how?

Tags: c#, sql-server

The C# code:

```
   SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro,@xp,@lv,@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@im);", c);
        NewUser.Connection = c;
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFName.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLName.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", txtprofession.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", DBNull.Value);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xp", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", 1);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m4", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m5", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@im", );
        Session["CurentUserid"] = txtuser.Text;
        c.Open();
        NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
        Session["Conect"] = (bool)true;
        Response.Redirect("Finish Had Member.aspx", true);
```

the table code:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Username]  VARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   VARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
    [FName]     VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [LName]     VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [Location]  VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [Profesion] VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [email]     VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [gender]    VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [money]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [property]  VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [xp]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [level]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [mission1]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [mission2]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [mission3]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [mission4]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [mission5]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [did1]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [did2]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [did3]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [did4]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [did5]      INT             NOT NULL,
[image]     VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
```

I want to save an image from the c# page into the data base this is the html:

```
<input runat="server" id="pho" type="file" name="file[]" multiple="" accept="image/*" />
```

how can i do it?
i added all the insert code plss loke how can i save the image?

i update the code there is th full table

Comment: Try this : NewUser.Parameters.Add("@im", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            NewUser.Parameters["@im"] = image;

Comment: what should i put instide of image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744589/how-do-you-store-a-picture-in-an-image-column/744603#744603

Comment: The byte[] for the image.  Make sure when reading the image from a file use UTF8 Encoding and not a string.  Putting an image into a string will corrupt the image data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for storing image to sql server :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    int imageLength = uploadInput.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] picbyte = new byte[imageLength];
    uploadInput.PostedFile.InputStream.Read (picbyte, 0, imageLength);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ImageTable (ImageFile) VALUES (@Image)", conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
    command.Parameters[0].Value = picbyte;

    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** uploadInput is a file input control, to upload image file to server. The code taken from an ASP.NET application.

Here is the insert script to an image typed column :

```
INSERT INTO ImageTable (ImageColumn)

SELECT ImageColumn FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\SampleImage.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) 
AS ImageSource(ImageColumn);
```

**EDIT :**  To know more on this topic, refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Us)

Comment: i dont succeed to do it with my database lots of errors someone can send an answer that will insert corectly with the image plss?

Comment: What s the error u get?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..

     Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro,@xp,@lv,@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@im);", c);
        NewUser.Connection = c;
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFName.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLName.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", txtprofession.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", DBNull.Value);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xp", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", 1);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m4", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m5", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", 0);
        NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@im", bytes);
        Session["CurentUserid"] = txtuser.Text;
        c.Open();
        NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
        Session["Conect"] = (bool)true;
        Response.Redirect("Finish Had Member.aspx", true);
```

**

> EDIT:     ok, I tried it on my system. Below code inserts the image in
>   binary format successfully.

**

SQL table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image_table](   

    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [image]     VARBINARY (MAX) NULL
    )



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream fs = FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

         string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionKey"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString);

            try
            { 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[Image_table]  values (@img)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

    }
```

Comment: i dont think it will work i need to insert them all in one time?

Comment: User will click on browse > Select the image file > then the control will come to first line of this code, and then the image will gets saved in DB one at a time, as you said you need to save an image in DB. Use FileUpload control. If you want to save multiple images, use a for loop.

Comment: ok but how can i exucate the first full insert without the img

Comment: I edited the answer.. I assume @im is your image variable.. you need to save bytes as its value.

Comment: the strean fs is an error what should i had at the using?

Comment: using System.IO; C'mon, you really need to read things and learn how visual studio works.

Comment: i know :( this is my second web!!!

Comment: Does not workingl it is showing the same things at the data table data: 0x every time

even if dont put image