# Insert a picture in a database

Tags: c#, database, image, insert

```
Image img =fromcomputer.Image;
byte[] arr;
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

string uploadpic = "insert into mypic(Data) values('" + arr + "',"  + "@Image)";
MySqlExtended.dbaccess.f_exec_string(uploadpic, connString);
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Image", fromcomputer));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525189/saving-image-in-sql-data-base-how/37525417#37525417 check for my answer. It might help you.

Comment: What is the dataType specified for your image column in the database? And what exception are you getting?

Comment: Tyvm to take time to answer my question but it's ok i found how to do it !